# Visual Studio Installer, SqlServerCe, and 64-bits

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, sql-server-ce

I'm working on a new VS2010 Solution that is going to have to have a Windows and a Web Installer (two separate setup projects).

At the heart of my VS2010 Solution is the database: **SQL Server CE 3.5 SP1**

I know that 64-bit machines need both the 32-bit version of `SqlServerCe` and the 64-bit versions of SqlServerCe.

I know how to add custom installer scripts to check that both 32 and 64 bit versions are there and that their version numbers match up in the registry.

My setup projects show `SqlServerCe` as one of the detected dependencies.

So, my question is, **do I need to use my custom installer scripts specified above to check for the right versions, or will the installer add these if they are not already on the system?**

Comment: FYI: I'm on a 64-bit system running Win7 and I do not have a 32-bit system to test on ...at the moment.

Comment: Why not use private deployment?

Comment: You mean walk out to each PC and install it by hand? That'd take forever, and some of these reps live in other states and other countries.

Comment: No, Ido not mean sneakernet :-) - see these 2 blog posts, then you do not need to worry about other dependencies than .NetFx: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/sql-server-compact-private-deployment.html and http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html